# How to start an activity from a plain non-activity java class?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I want to implement MVVM pattern using data-binding in my app. Here's the login button from my layout file:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/login"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="@{mainViewModel.name}"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:onClick="@{mainViewModel.startNewActivity}"/>
```

The logic is, on clicking this login button, a new activity should be started. I'm a beginner in android, and my question is should I keep the startActivity part in my MainActivity or in my ViewModel class? (If I want it to be in accordance with the MVVM pattern)

If it should be in the mainActivity, I would replace the last line with 
`android:onClick="startNewActivity"` and then define the method in my MainActivity.

But, if it is to be placed in the ViewModel class, declaring the following method:

```
public void startNewActivity(View view) {
    Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.class, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(login);
}
```

is giving error:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(java.lang.Class<package.name.MainActivity>,java.lang.Class<package.name.LoginActivity>)'
```

How do I start the LoginActivity from my ViewModel class then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start LoginActivity from  MainActivity  then 
 you have to pass this class in intent on button click event.
like this,

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel extends BaseObservable 
{ 
    public String name; 
    Context con; 
    public MainViewModel(Context context)
    { 
        this.con = context; 
    }  
public void click(View view) 
 { 
   Intent login = new Intent(con, LoginActivity.class); 
   con.startActivity(login); 
  } 
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,  R.layout.activity_main);
  MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(MainActivity.this);
  binding.setMainViewModel(mainViewModel);
 }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
  public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.login);
}
 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_hiehgt="20dp"
    android:onClick="@{mainViewModel.click}"/>
```

Comment: I can already start my login activity from main activity. What I want to know that if I can start the login activity from a ViewModel class?

Comment: @Akeshwar,Can u post ur proper code,so I can understand what is ViewModelClass???

If your View Model Class is Non Activity Class then you can use like this ,
public class ViewModel  {
    Context con;

     public ViewModel(Context context) {
         this.con= context;
     }

  public void startNewActivity() {
   Intent i = new Intent (con, LoginActivity.class);
   con.startActivity(i);
  }
     
}

Comment: Here is my ViewModel class. It's a non-activity class.
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4206

Comment: Then change code :
public class MainViewModel extends BaseObservable {
 
    public String name;
 Context con;
 
  public MainViewModel(Context context) {
         this.con = context;
     }
 
    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.example.satpracticeapp.BR.name);
    }
 
 
    public void click(View view) {
        Intent login = new Intent(con, LoginActivity.class);
        con.startActivity(login);
    }
}

Check and let me know if any issue then pls.

Comment: and also change ur method name as u have passed in xml file :

 public void startNewActivity() {
        Intent login = new Intent(con, LoginActivity.class);
        con.startActivity(login);
    }

Comment: And from where you want to access this method there you  have to call this code,
like in Sample activity you want to access then in sample activity you have to write this code 

MainViewModel mainViewModel=new MainViewModel(Sample.this);
 mainViewModel.startNewActivity();

Comment: I passed the context from mainActivity to my viewModel class.
 `public void click(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }`
This is how I'm starting the loginactivity now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98542/discussion-between-akeshwar-and-parul).

Comment: As discussed with you change the code and check.also updated above post.

Comment: Thanks pang for reply ,I read that page But If I have selected one header and try to apply this CTRL+B.but its not become bold.its display like **header**

Answer (score 0):

change like below.

```
Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(login);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gave me another error:
`package.name.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class`

Comment: Replace the line MainActivity.this with getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot start Activity from a custom class eg: Employee. All you can do is change the Architecture of your application so that you can start an Activity on some button click in the `MainActivity`.

and then to start

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
```

where `MainActivity.this` is the context and `LoginActivity.class` is that Activity to be started.

Comment: unfortunately, I got this error:
`package.name.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class`. I had already declared the activity in the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: @Akeshwar: ould u like to start the disccussion in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98528/how-to-start-an-activity-from-other-activity

Comment: I searched a bit more and found that it's possible to start an activity from a custom class if I pass the application context of the MainActivity to the custom class. I just did it. But now my major concern is if it's right to do this way?

Answer (score 0):

first argument of `Intent` will be context, not class. Replace your first argument with `MainActivity.this`

```
new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
```

Comment: After changing it to context, I'm now getting this error:
`'package.name.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class`

Comment: Besides, I also want to know that If my project needs to follow the MVVM pattern, then should I declare this starting new activity in my ViewModel class or in my MainActivity class?

Answer (score 0):

First create new activity(MainActivity).check the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

create another activity(LoginActivity).
LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="LoginBtn"
    android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gami.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm trying to implement the model-view-viewModel pattern in my app. SO, I want to start the LoginActivity from my ViewModel class.